# Take Smallest Group by Average

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to filter a set for the group with the smallest average value. In the example below, we'd group by ID, get the average year, and then only keep the group with the smallest average year. This feels basic, but I haven't seen an answer for it yet.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   'YEAR' : [2011,2012,2012,2013,2013,2014], 
                   'V': [0,1,1,0,1,0],
                   'C':[00,11,22,33,44,55]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
In [180]: min_id = df.groupby("ID")["YEAR"].mean().idxmin()

In [181]: df.query("ID == @min_id")
Out[181]:
   ID  YEAR  V   C
0   1  2011  0   0
1   1  2012  1  11
```

- get the *index* of the minimum mean year having group
- filter the frame where ID is equal to that

---

this is how the aggregated mean looks like:

```py
In [182]: df.groupby("ID")["YEAR"].mean()
Out[182]:
ID
1    2011.5
2    2012.5
3    2013.5
Name: YEAR, dtype: float64
```

so the minimum is 2011.5, index of it is 1 (the ID).

Comment: Non-`query` method: `df[df.ID.eq(df.groupby('ID')['YEAR'].mean().idxmin())]`

Answer (score 1):

```
groups = df.groupby(['ID']).mean()
```

Then

```
groups.loc[groups['YEAR'] == groups['YEAR'].min()]
```